# jQuery ajax creating infinite loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to display data from Mysqli database via jQuery ajax but no matter how much I tinker the code I always get a infinite loop. Has anyone experienced similar situation while making ajax requests ?

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addList").on('click', function () {
       saveList('addNew');
    });
   displayLists(0,10);
});

        function displayLists(start, limit) {
            $.ajax({
                url:'http://localhost/acl/ajax.php',
                        method:'POST',
                        dataType:'text',
                        data: {
                            key:'displayLists',
                            start:start,
                            limit:limit
                        }, success: function(response) {
                            if(response != 'reachedMax') {
                                $('#zaListeProstor').append(response);
                                start += limit;
                                displayLists(start, limit);
                            } 
                        }
            })  
        }
```

Here is the PHP code :

```
if($_POST['key'] == 'displayLists') {

            $individual_user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

            $start = clean($_POST['start']);
            $limit = clean($_POST['limit']);

            $sql = "SELECT * from liste WHERE lista_author = $individual_user_id LIMIT $start, $limit";
            $select_all_lists = query($sql);
         if(row_count($select_all_lists) > 0) {

              $response = "";

            while($row = fetch_array($select_all_lists)) {

                  $response .= '
                       <tr>
                             <td>'.$row["lista_name"].' </td>
                             <td> <input type="button" value="View List" class="btn btn-primary"> </td>
                       </tr>

                  ';


             } 

             exit($response);

           } else {

            exit('reachedMax');
           }

      }
```

And this is my functions for the database you see above:

```
function row_count($result){

return mysqli_num_rows($result);

}



function escape($string) {
    global $con;

    return mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $string);


}

function confirm($result) {

    global $con;

    if(!$result) {

        die("QUERY FAILED" . mysqli_error($con));

    }

}



function query($query) {

    global $con;

    $result =  mysqli_query($con, $query);

    confirm($result);

    return $result;


}





function fetch_array($result) {

    global $con;


    return mysqli_fetch_array($result);



}
```

Comment: `if(response != 'reachedMax') {` must never evaluate to false

Comment: Willing to bet you are returning more than the string `console.log(escape(response))`. This is a good example of why it is better to return JSON so you do not have to worry about whitespace and such in the response.

Comment: What gets appended? Your DB table doesn't have infinite rows, so what happens after all rows are appended? But yes, definitely use `console.log` for some very basic debugging.

Comment: When I console log the response I get my database once. Normal. So the problem is in my success: function(response) ... But there should not be  a problem :/

Comment: `console.log(Date.now(), response)` inside your success callback.  Are you sure it's only executing once?  (the Date.now() is there to keep the browser from consolidating console logs into a single entry)

Comment: Chris, my rows just keep appending. Round and round, infinite loop style.

Comment: Taplar different dates every loop. When I include console log after succes function, but if I only use console log the response it does not loop. One time, one output.

Comment: How about the second part?  The second part should be changing to be the advancing pages you are requesting.

Comment: I dont understand second part ? The whole ajax.php file (the one I am POSTING to) is looping in console.log and every time the time output is different.

Comment: I had you log a time stamp and the response.  You should be seeing the response change as the server returns paging data, ending with the expected terminating string.  What are you seeing for the changing response?

Answer (score 0):

> A response is html change datatype and response header

```
function displayLists(start, limit) {
            $.ajax({
                url:'http://localhost/acl/ajax.php',
                        method:'POST',
                        dataType:'HTML',
                        data: {
                            key:'displayLists',
                            start:start,
                            limit:limit
                        }, success: function(response) {
                            if(response != 'reachedMax') {
                                $('#zaListeProstor').append(response);
                                start += limit;
                                displayLists(start, limit);
                            } 
                        }
            })  
        }
```

set ajax.php response header

```
header('Content-type: text/javascript,text/html');
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but it still the same infinite loop.